# getting the id of an element in jquery onlclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

this is a very simple example of a html page

```
<span class ="title" id="title_1">this is</span> 
<span class="toggle" id="toggle_1>paragraph 1</span>

<span class ="title" id="title_2">this is</span> 
<span class="toggle" id="toggle_2">paragraph 2</span>
```

im trying to do an onlcick event with the toggle functon, so basically when the user clicks title_1 the toggle_1 will hide and show, and if the user clicks title_2 it will show and hide toggle_2, i hope this makes sense.

```
 (document).ready(function() {
      $('.toggle').hide();
        $('#title_').click(function() {
        $('#toggle_').toggle('slow');
    });
      });
```

i started my jquery like this, just don't know what to do from here. thanks

Comment: As a side note: I would use CSS to hide the toggle elements instead of jquery. Otherwise it will only be hidden after the dom has loaded which could take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
$('.toggle').hide();
$('.title').click(function() {
   $(this).next(".toggle").toggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(document).ready(function() {
      $('.toggle').hide();
      $('.title').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.toggle').toggle('slow');
      });
});
```